# Convert this SQL statement to Laravel Eloquent Relations

Tags: sql, laravel, eloquent

I have 2 tables

```
table1
empid
lname
fname
```

```
table2
empid
name
department
```

This is my SQL Statement

```
Select table1.*, table2.department from table1 inner join table2 on table1.empid = table2.empid
```

Comment: please refer laravel documentation. It's pretty clear. If you are stuck somewhere then post question

Comment: If you want to use `Eloquent Relations` you have to use `Models` to access them. Start there please, the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.3) explain it so easily.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```
table1
id
lname
fname

table2
id
table1_id
name
department
```

table2.php model

```
class Table2 extends Model
{
protected $primaryKey = 'id';

function withTable1() {
   return $this->hasOne('App\Table1', 'id', 'table1_id');
}

public function show($id){
     Table2::with('withTable1')->where('table1_id', $id)->get();
}
```

}

$id is a parameter of url